# How to List All Locations in MapPoint 2009 within a PlaceCategory using .NET (C# or VB.NET)?

Tags: .net, com, mappoint

I have MapPoint 2009 installed and added a reference to the "Microsoft MapPoint 16.0 Object Library (North America)" COM component to my C# project.

If I do the following, I can get a list of all the "places" within a specific city:

```
var m = new MapPoint.Application();
var map = m.ActiveMap;
MapPoint.FindResults r = map.FindPlaceResults("West Bend, WI");
```

However, is there a way I can query just all the "Police Stations" only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this can't be done with MapPoint 2009.

Answer (score 0):

A bit slow here Chris, but I wasn't a member in 2009!

You can set the display to "Police Stations only" both in the GUI and the API. Can you try that?

Also, you could go through the list of all POIs  and pick out the police stations.

I know I've coded something along these lines a few years back. The application was for travel kiosks - so things like "night clubs around this point" could be queried. I'd have to go back to my code, but it is definitely possible using one of the above methods.

Comment: Just looking at something else in the docs, you need the "FindNearby()" method. This queries all visible PlaceCategory objects. So set "police stations" (and only police stations) to visible, then use FindNearby() instead of findPlaceResults().